# What would cause bubbles in turkey stock?

Tags: food-safety

I made the stock the day after making turkey. Left the stock to cool overnight in a cool place. There were bubbles on it today. Removed carcass and started to reheat. Bubbles really forming. I have never seen this!!!

Comment: How cool was the place you left it overnight?

Comment: When you say bubbles, so you mean like a foamy later, almost like dirty washing up liquid? If so, this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would ditch the stock. It is unsafe to leave the carcass in the stock once you are done with the cooking. I was trained by my Oma to always a) strip the carcass as soon as it is cool enough to handle, b) use the carcass immediately if making stock or broth from it, and c) remove all bones and pieces from the stock as soon as it is removed from heat. If your stock is reactive, there is a chance it may not be safe to consume. Why take that chance?